# Is it possible to use different wifi IP on apps?

Tags: windows-10, networking, router, ip, ethernet

Basically, my question is, can you change the wifi IP on different sessions. Like you have a different wifi IP on YouTube and Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

A VPN browser extension with a whitelisting setting can do that. Site A (not on the whitelist) sees the VPN IP, whereas site B (which you have whitelisted) bypasses the VPN IP and sees your own IP.

If you want your own IP not to show on either site, you could deploy a VPN app that spoofs your IP on the computer level, together with a VPN browser extension. Then, when a site is whitelisted, it doesn't see the VPN IP served by the extension, neither your own IP, but the VPN app's IP.

For example, let's say your own IP is in New York. If you run the VPN app with a server in, say, Los Angeles, and the browser extension with a server in, say, Chicago, then sites not in the whitelist see Chicago, whereas whitelisted sites see Los Angeles. But nobody sees New York.